# In Tensorflow's Conv2D layer, is there a way to reuse the same kernel for all channels of the input?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
#input.shape = (N, H, W, C)
H = input.shape[1]
W = input.shape[2]
x_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=input.shape, name="base_input")
x_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, (H,W), activation='relu', input_shape = input.shape, data_format = "channels_last")(x_input)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = x_input, outputs = x_conv)
```

Would it be possible to make model.get_weights()[0].shape equal to (H, W, 1, 5) instead of (H, W, C, 5)?

I've looked through different implementations using Conv1D and Conv2D, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Depthwise Conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DepthwiseConv2D). It convolves over each channel separately. The number of filters can be controlled with the `depth_multiplier` parameter. The output shape for 1 input with height/width `H, W` and channels `C` would be `(1, H, W, C*depth_multiplier)`.

Comment: thanks for the response. So let's say I only want 1 set of kernel weights to be used to get one output channel (e.g. input_shape = (1,2,2,100), kernel_shape = (2,2), weight_shape = (2,2,1,1) and output_shape = (1,1,1,1)). I can not see how I can use Depthwise Conv2D to make weight shape (2,2,1,1). 

I am most interested in keeping the third (programmer's 2nd) dimension of weight_shape equal to 1.

One solution would be to pass each channel in separately and use the same conv2D layer on all 100 channels. Is there another way?

Comment: Another way would be to combine all the channels into one channel, then (since I'm only calling kernel once per channel) do stride size that is same as (H,W) of the channels. Still hoping there is a better way :)

Comment: I'm not sure I can really follow. If you have input shape `(1,2,2,100)` (100 channels) and want output shape `(1,1,1,1)`, you can just use normal `Conv2D` with kernel size `(2, 2)` and filter size 1. This will get you a weight size of `(2,2,1)`. In normal convolution the weight multiplication get summed up over the channels. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: I think, usually, when you have 100 input channels and you have 1 output channel, you end up getting (K_h, K_w, C_out, C_in) as your weight size and (H', W', C_out) as your output size. The C_in channels are summed to get you an output shape (H', W', C_out). 

Put a different way: the input channels get summed up, but even though we pass through (2,2) as our kernel, really we are passing a kernel of shape (2, 2, C_in) where each input channel has its own (2,2) kernel. I want all input channels to share one (2,2) kernel.

Comment: Trying to get real kernel size to be either (2, 2, 1) OR (2, 2, 100) but the weights for each (2, 2) should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yea just flatten your image. Image taking your three channels and tiling them into a single b&w image that's 3 times bigger.

Something like

```
image = tf.zeros(N, H, W, C)
image = tf.reshape(image, (N, H, W*C, 1))
```

Now run your Conv2D layer on it. It'll automatically pick up the fact that the image has C=1. when you are done, reshape it back.

```
image = tf.reshape(image, (N, H, W, C))
```

You could make all this a custom layer to hide the implementation as well.